# What is the use of object properties on JS arrays?? Is it standards-compliant?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In CMS code I stumbled upon this statement:

```
i18n = new Array();
i18n['PLUGIN_UPDATED'] = '<?php i18n("PLUGIN_UPDATED"); ?>';
i18n['ERROR'] = '<?php i18n("ERROR"); ?>';
```

When logged in the browser:

```
i18n // []
i18n instanceof Array // true
i18n instanceof Object // true
i18n.length // 0
i18n.ERROR // 'Error string'
```

The same applies for object literal construction (`var myArr = []`). I'm not sure what's going on but I suppose because arrays are subtypes of objects, their array content is only one of their properties? Is it good practice to 'exploit' this capability?

Comment: You've found code written by somebody who doesn't really know JavaScript very well. It's common, for example, for PHP programmers to assume that JavaScript arrays work like PHP arrays. They *sort-of* work the same, but they're different too.

Comment: It's absolutely standards-compliant. It's perfectly good practice to exploit the capability.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't know that I'd say "perfectly good practice", though it does work for many purposes. Things will work less well if, for example, there's a need to serialize the contents of the object with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @Pointy There's a good thread on this topic somewhere here on SO, now if I could only find it. As usual, opinions differed, with some being of the opinion that placing properties on arrays was the work of the Evil One himself. I myself would not place this in the category of wonderful programming paradigms, but if I have some metadata I need to hang off an array, hey why not. Your `stringify` point is well taken though.

Comment: I'm going to side with @Pointy on the "good practice" point. Someone expecting PHP-ish behavior from an array would be surprised to find, for example, that `JSON.stringify(i18n)` gives `[]`.

Comment: @Pointy & others thanks for the info, do you have a link or something to a page with more detailed info on these implications? I'm having a hard time finding any

Comment: It's not *always* bad, but like a lot of things what matters is whether the programmer really understands what's going on. There are lots of SO questions from PHP people (not to dump on them; it's just a common example) wondering why `i18n.length` isn't `2`, for example.

Comment: *"I suppose because arrays are subtypes of objects, their array content is only one of their properties?"* yes, arrays are special objects. Every element is actually a property of that object (try `console.dir([1,2,3])`).

Answer (score 1):

While this is probably* standards compilant, it isn't best practice as the following example illustrates:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3]
x.foo = 'bar';

var y = [1, 2, 3]

function iter(arr) {
    for(var x in arr) {
        console.log(arr[x]);
    }
}

iter(x); // 1, 2, 3, bar
iter(y); // 1, 2, 3
```

A better alternative here would be to use `Object.defineProperty` with the enumerable flag set to false.

Second reason why you don't want to do this is because of performance. VMs will treat your Array different when you start assigning arbitrary properties to them. In the V8, it might be as well possible that the following happens:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
// x holds only small integers (smis) and the VM will
// use an optimized representation for your array with
// random access and nice cache locality

x['foo'] = 'bar'; 
// when assigning a random property to your array, v8
// will transform it from the fast smi array to
// a hash map, not treating it as an array anymore
```

Remember that the hidden-class of an object changes as you assign properties to them. It makes it much harder for the VM to optimize these cases and turns otherwise monomorphic call sites into polymorphic, causes deoptimizations and other havoc.

Also note that every Array is an Object; no surprise there.

[*] I say only probably because I lack a link to the spec and I am not sure if this is true for "use strict" as well. It is for instance prohibited to add random properties to a String in strict mode.

Comment: All this shows is that you shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over array elements, and we all knew that already.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `Object.defineProperty`, now what would be really great would be a link to the docs/ spec/ use-cases/ implications..

Comment: @torazaburo That really depends on your use case. for..in skips undefined indices (which may or may not be what you want), doesn't require you to cache the length if you modify the array while iterating and is mucho shorter to write.